# Usb internet key & Raspberry: disable internet connection, used only for sms

Tags: connection, raspberry-pi3, internet-connection, huawei-mobile-services

I would like to use a USB internet Key Huawei E3531i for send and receive SMS.
I'm working on it, I can send but I have some issue receiving but this is not the topic of this thread.

When I plug the USB stick the Raspberry (connected to wireless lan) doesn't have access to internet any more. Most probably because somehow the internet key is considered as preferred connection but I don't have idea how to change this.

The best for me would be that the USB stick is not used at all for internet connection, even the wireless lan is not available.

How to configure this?
Thanks
Andrea

Comment: The usb internet key is configured as eth1.. nobody knows how to disable it? Should be enough I guess, I searched on the web but for example "sudo ifdown eth1" doesn't work, it says interface not existing but using ifconfig is visible.. ideas?

Comment: No.. I found how to disable eth1 (sudo ifconfig eth1 down) and it works but finally the internet key is not usable for sending/receiving sms..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
Editing the file: /etc/dhcpcd.conf

Adding the metric for each interface. In this way I can drive the priority of routing for internet connection:

```
interface wlan0
metric 200

interface eth1
metric 300
```

The smaller number has higher priority.

Now I'm able to reach the internet key with his static ip address but also connecting to internet because the default interface is the wifi.

Bye
Andrea